# how to remove all parenthese , brackets , dashes and white space using one regex command?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the string and I have managed to get rid of [] and ().

```
text='Lee  Jong-jae(Season1) Nam  Sung-woo[1]'
```

This one gets rid of both Parentheses and brackets?

```
 text.str.replace(r"[(\[].*?[\)\]]", "")
```

I tried to add regex for removing brackets and white spaces but to no avail.

```
text.str.replace(r"[(\[].*?[\)\]\\s-]+", "")
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Lee Jong jae, Nam Sung woo
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it and added the output I wanted.

Comment: Why did you remove `Season1`? That's not a parenthesis, bracket, etc.

Comment: You have an extra \ in your regex. Use `r"[(\[].*?[\)\]\s-]+"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text='Lee  Jong-jae(Season1) Nam  Sung-woo[1]'
pattern = r'(\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))|[\s-]+'
print(  re.sub(pattern, lambda m: ',' if m.group(1) else ' ', text).strip(', ') )
```

See the [Python  demo](https://ideone.com/wVGvzI).

Output:

```
Lee Jong jae, Nam Sung woo
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFfKAS/2).

*Details*:

- `(\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))` - Group 1: substrings between the closest square or round brackets
- `|` - or
- `[\s-]+` - one or more whitespaces or hyphens.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is a comma, else, it is a space. Extra commas or spaces are `strip`ped with `strip(', ')`.

Comment: If you could be kind enough to also help me in adding a comma between Lee Jong jae , Nam Sung woo. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @jaymerson There is a comma.